# Ext-js display calendar from Monday in Ext Date Menu

Tags: javascript, extjs, datepicker, sencha-architect

In `Ext.picker.Date` or `datePicker` we can set this as shown in below code.

```
var dateField=new Ext.form.DateField({
startDay: 1
});
```

But i am unable to do the same in `dateMenu`.Can anyone help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

did you try picker property?

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.menu.DateMenu  (under property)

Comment: Yes even in picker there is no **startDay** present.

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me, see the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hin).

To quote the [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/#!/api/Ext.menu.DatePicker):

> Notes:
>
> Although not listed here, the constructor for this class accepts all of the configuration options of Ext.picker.Date.

Comment: I am using sencha Architect and ext-js 4.2.1 in my application.  
In architect i cant do like this `var dateMenu = Ext.create('Ext.menu.DatePicker', {
            startDay: 1,
            handler: function(dp, date) {
                Ext.Msg.alert('Date Selected', 'You selected ' + Ext.Date.format(date, 'M j, Y'));
            }
        });`

Comment: still, works in the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/hin) I've updated the version and the start date is still working fine, just change startDay to 1 for Monday. Sencha Architect may not allow you to edit the code directly, I have not used it in a while, but the code itself works, Ext.menu.DatePicker does support that configuration option

Comment: this is the link of sencha documentaion for Ext.menu.DatePicker [http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.menu.DatePicker](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.menu.DatePicker).There is no configuration **startDay** present.

Comment: as my answer stated above: > Although not listed here, the constructor for this class accepts all of the configuration options of Ext.picker.Date. This means that all configuration options for Ext.picker.Date are there. You can see this in the documentation and you can see it working in the fiddle I provided.